# Laravel Relationship between 4 tables return property does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-10

This is my `vendor` table and Model Relation

```
// Migration, Table Structure
Schema::create('vendor', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id(); // Primary key
            $table->string('nama_vendor');
            $table->timestamps(); // Kolom created_at dan updated_at
        });

// Model Relation
public function pivotRab() {
        return $this->hasMany(RabItemPivot::class, 'vendor_id');
    }
```

This is my `detail_pekerjaan` table

```
// Table Structure
Schema::create('detail_pekerjaan', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('kode_proyek');
            $table->string('item');
            $table->string('ukuran');
            $table->string('keterangan');
            $table->decimal('harga_penawaran', 10, 2);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('kode_proyek')->references('kode_proyek')->on('project')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

This is my `rab_item` table

```
// Table Structure
Schema::create('rab_item', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->json('data');
            $table->integer('subtotal_material')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('subtotal_ongkos_kerja')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('total_material_ongkos_kerja')->default(DB::raw('(subtotal_material + subtotal_ongkos_kerja)'));
            $table->decimal('lain_lain_percent', 5, 2)->nulable()->default(0);
            $table->decimal('jasa_kontraktor_percent', 5, 2)->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->integer('grand_total')->default(DB::raw('(
                total_material_ongkos_kerja + 
                (total_material_ongkos_kerja * (lain_lain_percent / 100)) + 
                (total_material_ongkos_kerja * (jasa_kontraktor_percent / 100))
            )'));
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// Model Relation
public function rabPivotItem() {
        return $this->belongsTo(RabPivotItem::class, 'rab_item_id');
    }
```

This is my `pivot_table` that connect 3 of them

```
// Table structure
Schema::create('pivot_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('detail_pekerjaan_id')->constrained('detail_pekerjaan')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('vendor_id')->constrained('vendor')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('rab_item_id')->nullable()->constrained('rab_item')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

// Model Relation
public function detailPekerjaan() {
        return $this->hasOne(DetailPekerjaan::class, 'detail_pekerjaan_id');
    }

    public function vendor() {
        return $this->hasMany(Vendor::class, 'id');
    }

    public function rabItem() {
        return $this->hasOne(RabItem::class, 'rab_item_id');
    }
```

The pivot table is used to check which vendor not yet create an rab_item. So if :

- pivot_table.rab_item_id == null
- pivot_table.vendor_id = 1
- pivot_table.detail_pekerjaan_id = 2
- It means that Vendor who has id of 1 is not yet create an rab_item for detail_pekerjaan_id 2

The problem is how do I check it?? and get the vendor.vendor_name and vendor.id?? Fyi, I tried to display the name and id in the select option.

I already do this in my Controller

```
public function formRabItem($kode_proyek, $detail_pekerjaan_id)
    {
        // My other code

        $vendorList = RabItemPivot::where('detail_pekerjaan_id', $detail_pekerjaan_id)->where('rab_item_id', null)->get();

        // dd(RabItemPivot::where('detail_pekerjaan_id', $detail_pekerjaan_id)->where('rab_item_id', null)->get());

        return view('view_project.rabItem', compact('projectData', 'detailPekerjaan', 'vendorList'));
    }
```

And this is how i tried to display on my View

```
@foreach ($vendorList as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->vendor->id }}"
    {{ old('vendor_id') == $item->vendor->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>
    {{ $item->vendor->nama_vendor }}</option>
@endforeach
```

But it return error `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: `public function vendor()` returns a `hasMany()` relationship, which is a `Collection` when accessed via `$item->vendor`, so you can't do `$item->vendor->id`, since your code has no idea _which_ `id` you want (there's many). Your function name should be `vendors` so you don't make this mistake, and you'd have to do something like `$item->vendors->first()?->id`, or loop over them like `foreach($item->vendors as $vendor)`, then `$vendor->id` would return a the associated `id`.

Comment: okay i'll look it up. But since I'm newbie. any advice for my database structure?? is it  already good?? I'm just curious. Thanks in andvance.

Comment: Hard to say really... In my experience, as soon as you add another model to a pivot table (beyond the 2nd one), it stops being a pivot table, and you should treat it as a `one-to-many` from the original 3 tables (which it kinda looks like you're doing already, i.e. I don't see any `many-to-many` relationships, which would be a `belongsToMany()` in Laravel). But I can't really say for sure, since your table names aren't in English (except for `vendors`), and I can't discern what their purpose is and how they relate to each other...

Comment: ahhh i see thanks so much. still trying to apply your advice for the relationship models. ;)